# Question regarding Relational Operator in C?

Tags: c, relational

I am learning C language and I have some question as follows (sorry if these are silly ones)

I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 to run some examples:

```
int m=3, n=4, k = 2;
(1) printf("%d", k<m<n); => this one prints 1
(2) printf("%d", k>m>n); => this one prints 0
(3) printf("%d", m<n>k); => this one prints 0
```

As the book says "A zero value stands for false and any other value stands for true."
So, why the statement (3) prints 0 (false). I thought it should be 1, or what am i missing here?

Can anyone give me a clear explanation, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to C's precedence rules, `m<n>k` gets interpreted as `(m<n)>k` (your other examples follow the same form). `m<n` is true, so that evaluates to 1. Then the statement is actually `1>k` which is false, thus 0.

Comment: just to add on, even though an order of operations is specified, its good practice when things are ambiguous like this to explicitly group things, also, as yan explained you are actually first evaluating `(k < m)` and then `TRUE/FALSE < n`. If you wanted chained expressions like what one might write when doing math you should write `k < m && m < n`

Comment: +1, but the key here is that, unlike Python, `x < y < z` doesn't mean what we'd like it to mean in C (or most languages). You need to use `x < y && y < z`.